# parent_data = find_parent() TypeError: find_parent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pid'

Tags: python, json, datetime, sqlite, artificial-intelligence

Hi I am making a chatbot with python here is my code

```
import sqlite3
import json
from datetime import datetime

def find_parent(pid):
    try:
        sql = "SELECT comment FROM parent_reply WHERE link_id = '{}' LIMIT 1".format(pid)
        c.execute(sql)
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result != None:
            return result[0]
        else: return False
    except Exception as e:
        print("find_parent", e)
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_table()
    row_counter = 0
    paired_rows = 0

    with open ("C:/Users/harry/OneDrive/Desktop/reddit_data/2007/RC_2007-11".format(timeframe.split('-')[0], timeframe), buffering=1000) as f:
        for row in f:
            row_counter =+ 1
            row = json.loads(row)
            parent_id = row['parent_id']
            body = format_data(row['body'])
            created_utc = row['score']
            subreddit = row['subreddit']

        parent_data = find_parent()
```

and when I run that code I get the following error can anyone please help me

```
parent_data = find_parent() TypeError: find_parent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pid'
```

Comment: You need to add a pid to your line where you are stating that `parent_data = find_parent()`.

Comment: @Jack Moody so do you mean that i need to write parent_data = find_parent(pid)

Comment: @HarryO'c: Check my answer. You need `parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)`

Comment: Check the answer by @Bazingaa. Often times, if you read the error and find the location in your code you can figure it out.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for that I was really stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `find_parent(pid):` expects an argument to be passed during its execution call.

You are calling it as

```
parent_data = find_parent()
```

where you don't pass any argument. Hence the self explanatory error.

`pid` is a variable/argument for the function definition. Your actual id in the main function where you are calling `find_parent()` is stored under the variable `parent_id`. You need to pass the `parent_id` whose value will be assigned to `pid` as

```
parent_data = find_parent(parent_id)
```